# JavaScript object.value is not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple HTML form. I wanted to change the value of the input field onfocus and onblur.

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');

name.onfocus = function () {
    if (name.value == 'Your Name') {
        name.value = '';
    }
}

name.onblur = function () {
    if (name.value == '') {
        name.value = 'Your Name';
    }
}
```

([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eunushosen/nt76T/))

It works perfectly on Firefox, but no in Chrome. My chrome version is 26.0.1410.64 m.

Comment: why can't you just use `placeholder` in the form?, and it is working fine on chrome too.

Comment: I am using Chrome version 26.0.1410.65.

It works fine for me.

Comment: I know I can use placeholder. But I was just testing and wondering why it is not working!

When I use document.getElementById('name').value it returns the value of the input field, but I am storing the object, it is not working.